# Matching a regex pattern into an URL when it have a specific number of segments

Tags: regex

I have urls like these:

```
example.com/test/testurl
example.com/test/test-url
example.com/test/testurl/content
example.com/test/test-url/content
```

I'm working on a redirect in here so, I need a regex to match the url when it has only 2 segments (like the 2 first ones) getting the second segment in a group, but to fail in all the others.

Here's the pattern I accomplished so far:

```
test\/(\w+)(?!\/)\b
```

This one matches the first url and fails on the third, great.

But it ends up matching the second and fourth url, capturing the word up to the dash. I'm pulling my hair out on this one, any pointers are appreciated. Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First throw out `\b`.  That's to match word boundaries and URLs can contain non-word characters.

I'm going to make the assumption that you're getting the url in its own string without any other accompanying text.

That being the case the following regex will:

- match the start of a string
- match one or more characters up to the first forward slash
- match /test/
- match one or more characters up to another slash
- optionally match a slash
- match the end of a string

**REGEX**

```
^[^/]+/test/[^/]+/?$
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/xon1j7)

```
NO MATCH: example.com/test/
MATCH: example.com/test/testurl
MATCH: example.com/test/test-url
MATCH: example.com/test/test-url/
NO MATCH: example.com/test/testurl/content
NO MATCH: example.com/test/test-url/content
```

Also if you need to add the protocol, you can rewrite the regex thusly:

```
^[^:]+://[^/]+/test/[^/]+/?$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?=[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*$).*
```

Try this. This will match only if url has 2 segments. See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/gG5fF6/3

Comment: This one worked nicely. but I used the segment count as an example, would rather rely on the fixed text 'test' as I used on the example. For that reason alone I chose another one, but thanks for the time and accurate answer, appreciate it. :)

Comment: @ErickMartim thought you were after a generic one.Thanx :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex instead:

```
test/([^/]+)
```

It will capture everything that is not a slash after `test/`.

Escape the slashes appropriately if needed.

Comment: This one is matching all the strings. I actually wanted something that would match just the first two, but thanks for the answer.